# Why active admin doesn't delete an item rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am using active_admin gem on rails 4. I was able to register an item. 
I am able to add a new one but when I am trying to delete an item I have no luck. 
I am tracing the following error.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/active_admin.js"):
```

I don't know where should I start the debugging from.

Answer (score 0):

can you at least post your route file and what object you are trying to delete? The more info provided, the easier for someone to help

Comment: I really don't think that this has something to do with it I am tracing the console and getting a 404 Not Found
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/javascripts/active_admin.js
I guess it uses this on the delete action because the rest are working fine.

Comment: you can check whether you have javascript installed properly, try install 'therubyracer'. And make sure you run the install script for active_admin

Comment: This isn't an answer. It should be a comment! :)

Comment: yeah, I know, but at that time, I didn't have enough point to comment and I didn't know any other way to reply :(